# What is the difference between green threads and virtual threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

*Green Threads* have been implemented with Java 1.1 and dropped in subsequent Java versions, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_thread.

Java 19 introduced *Virtual Threads* as a preview feature.
https://openjdk.org/jeps/425

Both threads seem to work in User Space and not in Kernel Space as Javas Native Threads do.

**What's the difference between them, and are the previous limitations of Green Threads omitted with the new Virtual Threads?**

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### **Short Answer:**

Green Threads had an N:1 mapping with OS Threads. All the Green Threads ran on a single OS Thread. With Virtual Threads, multiple virtual threads can run on multiple native threads (n:m mapping)

### A bit more details from the [JEP 425](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425)

- Java's green threads all shared one OS thread (M:1 scheduling) and were eventually outperformed by platform threads (Java's Native Threads) implemented as wrappers for OS threads (1:1 scheduling)
- Virtual threads employ M:N scheduling, where a large number (M) of virtual threads is scheduled to run on a smaller number (N) of OS threads.

### Just a small overview

| Thread Type | Description | Java Thread Type (M) : Native Threads(N) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Platform Threads | A wrapper for OS Threads. | 1:1 |
| Green Threads | Runs multiple "Green Threads" on a single OS Thread. | M:1 |
| Virtual Threads | Runs multiple Virtual Threads on Multiple OS threads | M:N (M > N) |

### **Full Quote from JEP**

> Virtual threads are a lightweight implementation of threads that is
> provided by the JDK rather than the OS. They are a form of user-mode
> threads, which have been successful in other multithreaded languages
> (e.g., goroutines in Go and processes in Erlang). User-mode threads
> even featured as so-called "green threads" in early versions of Java,
> when OS threads were not yet mature and widespread. However, Java's
> green threads all shared one OS thread (M:1 scheduling) and were
> eventually outperformed by platform threads, implemented as wrappers
> for OS threads (1:1 scheduling). Virtual threads employ M:N
> scheduling, where a large number (M) of virtual threads is scheduled
> to run on a smaller number (N) of OS threads.

Answer (score -1):

The important part of virtual threads is not that they are multi-core (for a server, number of cores obviously not an IO bottleneck), but the fact that all blocking operations are translated into non-blocking ones that use something like epoll below the hood, with a single coordinator thread in the background running an event loop that wakes up the virtual threads when the file descriptor they were waiting on is ready.

By contrast, if you did a blocking wait for IO with the old green threads, it forced *all* green threads to wait. In other words, the old green threads did not make IO easy and still forced you into manual asynchronous programming, while virtual threads are designed to make asynchronous IO trivial much like Go's goroutines.

Since green threads could not be used to wait for many things at the same time, they were outperformed by platform threads where the OS scheduler could wake them up on IO (at the cost of an expensive context switch). Not because of being single-threaded, but because they couldn't even wait for many things at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

Java's green threads all shared one OS thread (M:1 scheduling) and were eventually outperformed by platform threads (Java's Native Threads) implemented as wrappers for OS threads (1:1 scheduling) Virtual threads employ M:N scheduling, where a large number (M) of virtual threads is scheduled to run on a smaller number (N) of OS threads.